# Как в цикл, перебирающий json добавить еще один json-обьект jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть код, который загружает и перебирает json,

```
jQuery.each(response.items, function(index, item) {
text += '<li class="item"><a href="' + item.product.url + '" title="' + item.title + '" class="product-image"><img src="' +image+ '" width="50" alt="' + item.title + '"></li>';
});
```

В него надо вывести данные из еще одного json обьекта, некоторые "ключ-значения" у них одинаковые например json 1:

```
{[ "id": "123", 
   "title": "qwerty"],
 [ "id": "456", 
   "title": "asdf"]}
```

json 2:

```
{[ "id": "123", 
   "img": "http://google.com"],
 [ "id": "456", 
   "img": "http://vk.com"]}
```

Надо перебрать в цикле json 1, но один параметр взять с json 2, если id совпадает. Помогите пожалуйста советом, как такое сделать можно

Answer (score 0):

Можно из исходных "json'ов", которые есть массивы объектов как я понял, собрать объекты (словари), где ключи – id, а значения объекты целиком. Например:

```
// было
[ { "id": "123", "title": "qwerty"}, ..

// стало
{ "123":  { "id": "123", "title": "qwerty"}, ..
```

Так удобно по id находить все данные. Потом останется только пробежаться по всем id из первого, и если есть с таким же id из второго, скопировать все поля:

```js
var json1 = [
    { "id": "123", "title": "qwerty"},
    { "id": "456", "title": "asdf"},
];

var json2 = [
    { "id": "123", "img": "http://google.com"},
    { "id": "456", "img": "http://vk.com"},
];

function json2dict(J) {
  var i, el, D = {};
  for(i in J) {
    el = J[i];
    D[el.id] = el;
  }
  return D;
}

var D1 = json2dict(json1);
var D2 = json2dict(json2);

var Ids1 = Object.keys(D1);
var Ids2 = Object.keys(D2);

var i, id;
for( var i = 0; i<Ids1.length; i++) {
  id = Ids1[i];
  if( !!~Ids2.indexOf(id)) {
    for(attr in D2[id]) {
      D1[id][attr] = D2[id][attr];
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('out').innerText = JSON.stringify( Object.values(D1));
```

```css
#out{font-family:Courier New,monospace}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```